# How can I delete the Argo events launched in the Argo namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, events, namespaces, argo

I am trying to delete (and recreate) the Argo namespace, but it won't fully delete because I tried launching an eventsource and eventbus there. Now these will not delete.

I have tried to delete them via yaml and individually - no success yet.

The frustrating result is that I cannot re-launch argo

```
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterworkflowtemplates.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/cronworkflows.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workfloweventbindings.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workflows.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workflowtasksets.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workflowtemplates.argoproj.io unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-aggregate-to-admin unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-aggregate-to-edit unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-aggregate-to-view unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-cluster-role unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-server-cluster-role unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-binding unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/argo-server-binding unchanged
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": serviceaccounts "argo" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": serviceaccounts "argo-server" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "argo-role" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "argo-binding" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": configmaps "workflow-controller-configmap" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": services "argo-server" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": services "workflow-controller-metrics" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": deployments.apps "argo-server" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.2.0/install.yaml": deployments.apps "workflow-controller" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace argo because it is being terminated
```

Here is what is going on in the argo namespace itself

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Namespace",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-10-21T14:52:51Z",
        "deletionTimestamp": "2021-12-10T18:48:17Z",
        "labels": {
            "kubernetes.io/metadata.name": "argo"
        },
        "name": "argo",
        "resourceVersion": "9222845",
        "uid": "2ce61352-74a5-40d1-b35e-fe1efa39c3af"
    },
    "spec": {
        "finalizers": [
            "kubernetes"
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2021-12-10T18:48:23Z",
                "message": "All resources successfully discovered",
                "reason": "ResourcesDiscovered",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2021-12-10T18:48:23Z",
                "message": "All legacy kube types successfully parsed",
                "reason": "ParsedGroupVersions",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2021-12-10T18:48:23Z",
                "message": "All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization",
                "reason": "ContentDeleted",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "NamespaceDeletionContentFailure"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2021-12-10T18:48:23Z",
                "message": "Some resources are remaining: eventbus.argoproj.io has 1 resource instances, eventsources.argoproj.io has 1 resource instances",
                "reason": "SomeResourcesRemain",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "NamespaceContentRemaining"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2021-12-10T18:48:23Z",
                "message": "Some content in the namespace has finalizers remaining: eventbus-controller in 1 resource instances, eventsource-controller in 1 resource instances",
                "reason": "SomeFinalizersRemain",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "NamespaceFinalizersRemaining"
            }
        ],
        "phase": "Terminating"
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Even though one test of Kubernetes shows that the eventsource persists, another test shows that it does not

This is the response to
kubectl get eventsources argo

```
Error from server (NotFound): eventsources.argoproj.io "argo" not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles onto this question, it is a permissions issue. Make certain your service account has permissions to work in both namespaces (argo and argo-events).